# Solve line integral using Green's thereom

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Given $\oint_c x^2+y^2dx + 2xydy $ and C is the boundry R bounded by the graphs of $y=\sqrt{x}, y = 0, x = 4.$ 
Here is what I have so far :
$$\oint_c x^2+y^2dx + 2xydy = \int\int_R (\frac{dn}{dx}-\frac{dm}{dy})$$
$$ M(x,y) = x^2 + y^2, \space N(x,y)=2xy$$
$$\oint_c x^2+y^2dx + 2xydy = \int\int_R\ (\frac{d}{dx}(2xy) - \frac{d}{dy}x^2 + y^2 dydx ) $$
$$= \int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} (2y -2y)dydx$$

Would this just equal 0, or after applying the integral would it become y and then be evaluated at the points, as I know y would become 1 when using the derivative not 0. Is it that  I set this up incorrectly ?

Comment: The integrand is exact and you’re integrating over a closed curve, so...

Comment: soooo ? what does that mean the total length of this line can't be zero right ?

Comment: You’re not computing arc length. The line integral of an exact form over a closed curve is zero, so you’re getting the right answer.